# setting the Internet explorer version

Tags: internet-explorer

I have Internet explorer version 11 installed on my Machine. Every time I run the my web application, it is using the lower version ( version 7). I changed its version in developer tool but it worked for one time only. When I run next time, it is resetting back to 7 again. Is there any way to change version to 11 other than doing it from developer tool?

Comment: Set [`X-UA-Compatible`](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible) as a meta tag or an HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the X-UA-Compatible meta tag in the head of your html.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
```

That sets it to use IE Edge. See the following link for more details:

[How to use X-UA-Compatible](https://www.modern.ie/en-gb/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible)